# Calculating average for last X number of records

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to calculate the average of a field for the last (2) times it occurs.

For example this is a sample dataset

```
Name    VLoad   Sload   Timestamp
DT5227  254.1   270.5   19-09-2018 33:22 PM
DT5237  237.1   278.5   19-09-2018 33:22 PM
DT5237  237.1   278.5   19-09-2018 33:20 PM
DT5227  254.1   266     19-09-2018 33:20 PM
DT5237  237.1   278.5   19-09-2018 33:18 PM
DT5227  254.1   270.8   19-09-2018 33:18 PM
DT5227  254.1   273     19-09-2018 33:16 PM
DT5237  237.1   278.4   19-09-2018 33:16 PM
DT5227  254.1   273.1   19-09-2018 33:14 PM
DT5237  237.1   278.5   19-09-2018 33:14 PM
DT5227  254.1   275.8   19-09-2018 33:12 PM
DT5237  237.1   278.6   19-09-2018 33:12 PM
DT5237  237.1   278.6   19-09-2018 33:10 PM
DT5227  254.1   268     19-09-2018 33:10 PM
DT5237  237.1   278.6   19-09-2018 33:08 PM
DT5227  254.1   266.9   19-09-2018 33:08 PM
DT5237  237.1   278.5   19-09-2018 33:06 PM
```

Now there are many "Names" but I was trying to calculate the average of VLoad for the last 5 instances for every name in the list.

My effort:

```
var groups = (from x in _unitOfWork.Repository<Trucks>().Queryable()
group x by new {x.Name,x.Timestamp}
into gResult
select new
{
    gResult.Key.Name,
    Average = gResult.Average(x => x.VLoad),
    gResult.Key.Timestamp
});

var result = groups.GroupBy(x => x.Name).SelectMany(x => x.OrderBy(r => r.Timestamp))
            .Take(2);
```

I am not exactly getting an intended result. Could someone help me fix my Linq query please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my guess is valid, this should fix your problem. [Try it online !](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NNuPR9)

```
public static void Main()
{
    var records = new []
    {
        new Record {Name = "DT5227", Vload = 0, Sload = 270.5, Timestamp = "18-09-2018 31:22 PM" },
        new Record {Name = "DT5227", Vload = 254.1, Sload = 270.5, Timestamp = "19-09-2018 31:22 PM" },
        new Record {Name = "DT5227", Vload = 264.1, Sload = 270.5, Timestamp = "19-09-2018 33:22 PM" }
    };

    var results = records.GroupBy(x => x.Name)
         .Select(x => x
             .OrderByDescending(r => r.Timestamp) // be sure to use DateTime here
             .Take(2) // take last two thanks to OrderByDescending
             .Select(r => r.Vload).Average()); // Builtin average!

    // do what you want with results
    Console.WriteLine(results.First());
}
```

Comment: @Navyseal feel free to ask if you have any questions on the code

Answer (score 0):

After retrieving all rows, ordered by name and timestamp, you could use a Queue data structure for iteratively adding values for each name and only use the last X additions for computing the average.

It's not the most efficient approach, but it will work.